# online payment safe in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: security

I would just like to know that is ubuntu and other linux distributions safe for online payments ??
the latest versions.
generally most people want web safety 
. People say that ubuntu is very secure so is it safe for online transactions or is there a catch involved ?

Comment: @vasa1 That overlaps in part with another very real issue--how to know the client software (e.g., web browser) that you are using, *and the site that you are visiting*, and the particular session through which you're communicating with the site, are acceptably safe for transferring sensitive information like credit card numbers. **fffdf** Those issues (that I just summarized) are a general computing matter that doesn't differ much from OS to OS, so it might be best to seek explanations from somewhere like [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/) (search the site first though please).

Comment: An operating system is as secure as you handle it. Use sane and secure passwords, don't install software from untrusted sources, lock your screen at all times away from it, install all updates, use a trusted DNS server, check SSL certificates, etc. And never do silly things like running a browser as root. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu by itself, but more with the user. **Use common sense.**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ubuntu is a highly secure and protected operating system, a number of steps have been taken to ensure that it is a highly secure OS. However, if one visits malicious sites and allows malicious content to enter their system, that is not something the OS or your web browser can prevent.

I've been using Ubuntu as my primary OS for about a year and  a half now, so a large number of hours have been clocked online, purchases have been made online and yet, i don't have an anti virus software installed on my system, so in conclusion I'd say that it is a largely safe OS.